# Blender 2.8 won't let me import reference images

Tags: modeling, import, image, customization

I have returned to blender after 6-7 months of not using it, and wow has it gone through some changes. I've been re-teaching myself this program, and have ran into a problem that people online can't answer, as it refers to earlier versions.

My problem is that I can't import reference images. I've tried using the import buttons, I've tried searching the program for background/reference image importing options, and even trying to just drag it in. Nothing is working. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome back to Blender

You import reference images by "adding" an **Image**, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and selecting the subcategory "Image"->"Reference".
[image]
A "File Browser" window will open where you select the image.
After you selected the image and confirm it, the image will appear in the viewport.
Further settings can be accessed by going in the "Object Data Properties".
[image]

By the way, dragging an image into the viewport works as well.
But i don't know where you tried to drag it to.

Happy Blending